# Calculate age in years, months or days in textbox w/datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

my question is how can I calculate age using datetimepicker in another textbox?

e.g. If user picks a 10/06/2014 date assuming today is 11/06/2014, textbox should show "1 day" 
or if user picks 02/03/2014, txtbox should show "3 months"

**This is my code for calculate age in years**

```vb
Private Sub BirthDate_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BirthDate.ValueChanged
    txtAge.Text = Fix((DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, BirthDate.Value, Now.Date)) / 365) & " years"
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the DateDiff specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

You're already using it, but if you want years, you don't need to divide the days by 365, you can use DateInterval.Year.

You can apply the same thing to other time intervals, you'll need to set parameters for when you'd like to use each.

For example (pseudocode):

```
if DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Birthdate.Value, Now.Date) < 30
print DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Birthdate.Value, Now.Date)

elseif 29 < DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Birthdate.Value, Now.Date) < 365
print DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Birthdate.Value, Now.Date)

elseif DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Birthdate.Value, Now.Date) > 365
print DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, Birthdate.Value, Now.Date)
```

I hope this helps!